# Magento product review visible in every language

Tags: magento, review

A product review is not visible in another language. How can I enable that for an other store-view with the same products?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to go into the review and set the store views it is visible in when you approve it. To update them all quickly you can do it with a sql update directly on the database. Would mean an english review would be visible in english on say a spanish store view though.

Comment: Is there a way to change the default so they are visible in all stores by default?

Answer (score 1):

Review for all store views:

- Export all review_id of review_store table. Add store_id to each review_id. You can do it manually using the editor Sublime (Select all lines and using Ctrl+Alt+L do edit all lines at once)
- Insert back into the table. Example of SQL:

  INSERT IGNORE INTO `review_store` (`review_id`, `store_id`) VALUES

  (9,1),
  (9,3),
  (9,4),
  (9,5),
  (9,6),
  (9,7),
  (9,10),
  (9,11),
  (9,12),
  (14,1),
  (14,3),
  (14,4),
  (14,5),
  (14,6),
  (14,7),
  (14,10),
  (14,11),
  (14,12),
  ...

On Magento Admin:

- Setup rating for the new store view. ( Catalog > Manage Ratings > Click on each rating and setup the rating visibility for each store)
- On the list of all reviews, select all "Approved" reviews, and change status to "Approved" ( this is just to save the reviews and generate the rating summary)